# Replace SAS stored process with different ETL tool

Tags: migration, azure-data-factory, etl, informatica

We are looking for replacement of existing calculation engine which is based on SAS ETL and multiple consecutive SAS Stored process.
We know that which ever tool selected, we need to re write logic from SAS stored process.
Currently we have a set of java developers .
So we are looking for a tool, which support ETL as well as  the support to call java programs (since we considered re writing sas programs to java )

Currently we considered ADF and informatica for the replacement.
We are not able to select the ideal tool. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as i understand, you have some SAS ETL procedures which you want to recreate in JAVA and then you have some SAS ETL which you want to run using some ETL program.

Here are my thoughts -

Informatica - A popular, age old, well tested and used, costly ETL tool. Yes, you can seamlessly combine JAVA programs in a mapping  stored procedure. But you need someone to create the maps and schedule them. Depending on complexity you may need an external scheduler like Control M, Autosys, Cybermation etc.
You can go with this tool if you have 100s of components and want to build efficient solution. Downside would be cost and i am not sure if all java libraries will work in infa.

ADF - nice cloud first tool. You can use this to build medium complex to simple ETL system. If you have future requirements like conforming data from multiple sources, logs, cloud sources, etc. this can be helpful. It also can call java procs and run ETL. Consider cloud costs as well - how many pipelines you need/how much data you want to process, uptime etc.

I would recommend Talend, this is a java based ETL tool which will save you lot of money and your java programmers will get a nice tool which look like ETL, do ETL but uses similar terminologies like java.